# read() from a HDD with O_DIRECT fails with 22 (EINVAL, Invalid Argument)

Tags: linux, io, hard-drive, block-device

I want to make a basic `read()` from a SATA HDD `/dev/sdd`. A `write()` seems to work. Also `read()` and `write()` works without the `O_DIRECT` Flag. I've read, that it has to be aligned to the blocksize. So I used this to get the blocksize:

```
root$ blockdev --getsize /dev/sdd
488397168

root$ blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sdd
250059350016

root$ python -c "print 250059350016.0/488397168"
512.0
```

As you can see I have root. The HDD is connected via a PCIe SATA Card and `lspci -vv` shows me, that it uses the basic ahci (`drivers/ata/ahci.c`) driver. 
I work with the 3.2.0 Linux Kernel on a 64 bit Power Architecture.

Here is my code:

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <errno.h>

int main() {

    int r;
    char *buffer, *tmp_buffer;
    // alloc more than necesarry to align the real buffer
    tmp_buffer = malloc(2*512*sizeof(char)); 
    long align = (unsigned long)tmp_buffer%512;
    printf("tmp_buffer is at: %x \% 512 = %d\n",tmp_buffer,align);

    buffer = tmp_buffer+(512-align);
    printf("buffer is at: %x \% 512 = %d\n",buffer,(unsigned long)buffer%512);

    memset(buffer,0,sizeof(512));

    // OPEN
    int fd = open("/dev/sdd",O_DIRECT | O_RDWR | O_SYNC);
    if(fd!=3) printf("fd = %d\n",fd);

    // READ
    printf("try to read and then dump buffer:\n");

    r = read(fd,buffer,sizeof(512));
    if(r == -1) printf("Error: %s\n",strerror(errno));
    else {
        // DUMP BUFFER
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<sizeof(512); i++)
            printf("%c",buffer[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
tmp_buffer is at: 1cc80010 % 512 = 16
buffer is at: 1cc80200 % 512 = 0
try to read and then dump buffer:
Error: Invalid argument
```

edit:
I have updated my source as suggested by Brett Hale's answer. Unfortunately I still get the error. Is my way to find out the blocksize ok? Have I done the aligning right?

Thank you very much for reading,
Fabian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Direct DMA transfer typically requires the buffer to be aligned. From `man`:

> The O_DIRECT flag may impose alignment restrictions on the length and address
>          of userspace buffers and the file offset of I/Os. ... Under Linux 2.6, alignment to 512-byte boundaries suffices.

So `char buffer[512];` might need to be aligned to a 512-byte address.

It may not be possible to achieve this alignment on the stack, so something like:

`static char buffer[512] __attribute__ ((__aligned__ (512)));`

may work. Or maybe this alignment will work on the stack. Alternatively, if you're using x86, you could use the `<mm_malloc.h>` intrinsic support functions: `_mm_malloc` and `_mm_free`.

Comment: ahh I have to align my buffer? I thought that the filepointer position always has to be aligned (so 0 is ok) and getting 512 Bytes to be aligned aftwerwards is the right way. I've updated my source code, but I still get the Error. Would you be so kind and check what I've done? :)

Comment: @samuirai, there's an interesting thread [here](http://kerneltrap.org/node/7563) (2.6.x) with comments from the boss.

Comment: Yes I've read this. For this project, speed and power failure proof is very important. I have to meassure the time how fast we can write. I'm too unknowing, to question this :/

Answer (score 1):

BTW, the alignment always need not be in multiples of 512 bytes. it depends on the device block size. You should find it using ioctl with the BLKSSZGET. If the read is not aligned to this value while using O_DIRECT, the read() will fail with EINVAL.